# Makefile for Running Django Backend and React Frontend

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reactjs, makefile

I am working on a project which is developed by Django REST Framework and served by React app.

There is a partition between the back end and front end. The structure of the path is:

```
Root
├── backend
├── frontend
├── makefile
├── readme.md
├── requirements.pip
└── venv
```

Currently, I run the project by opening two different terminals. Then I start the django server first and then start the react app.

In terminal 1, I start the django server:

```
cd backend
python manage.py runserver
```

In terminal 2, I start the react app:

```
cd frontend
npm start
```

So, it is quite irritating to redo these commands each time to run the project. Recently, I have heard about `makefile`. I think this will reduce the number of commands to start the project.

I have created the following `makefile`:

```
run:
    python backend/manage.py runserver
    cd frontend
    npm start
```

When I write `make run` it successfully starts the Django server but it does not start the React application.

What am I missing here? Can I run the both commands in a single command using `make`?

**Update:**
Problem is solved.

The updated `makefile` contains:

```
django:
    bash -c "python backend/manage.py runserver"

react:
    bash -c "cd frontend && npm start"

run:
    make django & make react
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python backend/manage.py runserver` is still running and hasn't returned yet, so the next command isn't executed.

One solution I can think of is using the `&` symbol so the second command doesn't need to wait for the first one to return:
`python backend/manage.py runserver & cd frondend && npm start`